# JPQL to SQL converter

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

Is it possible to access the SQL which is generated by JPQL?

I would like to use the SQL to later create a view for my purposes.

I am using Hibernate if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to write your own JPQL implementation then :-) After all, converting JPQL into SQL for an RDBMS datastore is what a JPQL implementation is. Good Luck!

Sure you could make use of an existing JPQL implementation though, whether Hibernate, or EclipseLink, or DataNucleus ... and since they are all open source you ought to go and dig in their codebase.

Answer (score 8):

> Is it possible to access the SQL which is generated by JPQL?

You can access the SQL `String` from an **Hibernate `Interceptor`**, more precisely from the method [`Interceptor.html#onPrepareStatement(java.lang.String)`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html#onPrepareStatement(java.lang.String))

```
onPrepareStatement
String onPrepareStatement(String sql)

    Called when sql string is being prepared.

    Parameters:
        sql - sql to be prepared 
    Returns:
        original or modified sql
```

If you decide to go this way, the best option is to extends [`EmptyInterceptor`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/EmptyInterceptor.html) and to override only the methods you want.

You can hook your interceptor using the following declaration in your `persistence.xml`:

```
<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor" value="com.acme.MyInterceptor"/>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `hibernate.show_sql` property to true, then all the SQL will be shown on the console.

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need the SQL accessible in my application programmatically.